# display only the names which are active syntax error

Tags: cakephp

i am trying to display only the names which are active in drop down list box in cakephp. My database is PostgreSQL.

i know there is something wrong with syntax:please point out the error:

```
$fields = array('id','moduleName');
    $modules = $this->Module->find('list',array('fields'=>$fields),array('conditions'=>array('isactive'=>'1',)));

        $select=$this->set(compact('modules'));
```

in my drop list it shows all the names which are isactive = 1 and 0.the condition is not being met.

Comment: `$select=$this->set()` - why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put conditions in other array, try like this

```
$fields = array('id','moduleName');
$modules = $this->Module->find('list', array(
    'fields'=>$fields,
    'conditions'=>array('isactive'=>'1')
));

$select=$this->set(compact('modules'));
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: let me know if any difficulty you've faced while implementing the above.